# How did Romaniotes wrap tefillin?

Tags: tefilin

Everyone knows that Sephardics and Ashkenazis wrap tefillin differently. But how did/do Romaniotes (from parts of Greece, mainly Ioannina) wrap it?

Comment: I assume you're referring to standing versus sitting while putting on the hand-tefillin, but can you [edit] to make that clearer?

Comment: Like this: https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=KLecUbnjirI

Comment: @Kazibácsi So basically they wrap tefillin like most Sepharadim.

Comment: @ezra This is what I definitely see there, although I'm not an expert. You should also note that many Italian Jews are _sefardim_ themselves (like Livorno, most of Venice). Unfortunately I can't ask my Roman friends now, but ב"נ I'll do later on.

Comment: @msh210 I actually assumed OP is asking about the wrapping on the hand.

Comment: I'd venture to assume the tefilin-wrapping was like the Sefardic tradition. Much of the Romaniote communities in Greece (aside from Ioannina; Patras, Preveza, Crete, Chalcis) were overwhelmed by Sefardim after the Spanish expulsion and, save for the liturgy in which *nusach* 'Roma' and *nusach* 'Italki' kept some old traditional peculiarities, they adopted Sefardic ritual.

Comment: @Oliver Here he says that this knot probably comes from Firenze, which was prone to "Sefardisation." I've asked a Roman guy now.