# Romaniote tune/chant for Torah reading

Tags: minhag, torah-reading

Would anybody happen to have audio records of the Romaniote (Greek, say from Janina) Torah readings?

How similar is it to nearby traditions? Say [Italian](http://www.archivio-torah.it/audio/parashot/02_noah.mp3), or [Turkish](https://zemirot.org/song/%D7%91%D7%A8%D7%90%D7%A9%D7%99%D7%AA/)?

Comment: related: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/94361/how-did-romaniotes-wrap-tefillin

Comment: IIRC it’s not like Italian *or* Turkish. I haven’t come across Torah readings but [here’s](http://devhost.wsg.co/archie/maftirim/cat/origin/romaniote/) samples of other readings (Psalms etc.). On a related note Cantor Haim Ishakis, a Romaniote Jew, has additional readings on his YouTube channel [here](https://m.youtube.com/user/MrIschakisHaim).

Comment: The first link you shared is the same website I linked :) But Ishakis' channel is interesting nevertheless.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't want to accept my own answer, but I found this video of [Shema](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-NPxMzky3kY) being recited in the Romaniote tradition with the te'amim. Also, the website of Kehila Kedosha Janina has some [samples](https://www.kkjsm.org/romaniote-liturgy) of their liturgy. They seem to be chanting the last portion of Shirat ha-yam according to the te'amim. The [link](https://zemirot.org/song/%D7%A2%D7%A8%D7%91%D7%99%D7%AA-%D7%A9%D7%9E%D7%A2/) @[Oliver](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/users/15571/oliver) shared also seems to contain a sample of Shema.

I'd still appreciate if somebody can provide me with another resource, and will probably accept their answer instead of mine.

Comment: There are a few recordings in the National Library of Israel: https://www.nli.org.il/he/items/NNL_MUSIC_AL000224810/NLI